# How to get value of some element from web page that resides on internet? (PHP or JavaScript)

Tags: php, javascript, get, remote-access

The problem is, I do not know how to get for example heading content from **remote** internet page.

For example:

If web page http:\www.test.com (it is remote page like google or youtube) contains:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = 'temperature'>32</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Whitch methods can be used to retrieve temperature value from this page?

I need to use languages as PHP or JavaScript...

But if there exists solution in another language, just put it here and it will may be helpful for other users (whitch are interested in languages as Ruby, Perl, Java, and so on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of cURL and SimpleXML to pull in the web request and parse the DOM as XML.

```
<?php

$URL = "http://yoururl.website";

$ch = curl_init($URL);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$domXML = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($ch));

curl_close($ch);

//Access the dom element you want
print '<pre>';
print_r($domXML);
print '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) library can help you do this in PHP. If the sourceforge link is dead for you as well, [this](https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser) might be a suitable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to see if the service you are fetching data from has an API.  This way you can get information directly from their database(where the functions allow).